# MBRIntersects MySQL returning empty

Tags: mysql, geometry, gis

I have a MySQL 5.6 Spatial Database with a table that contains about 50,000 polygons. I have the coordinates for a bounding box in the form of a WKT polygon and am needing to get all polygons from the database that are fully or partially within this box.

I'm currently trying with the following code, however its returning an empty result set.

```
SELECT * FROM `polygons` WHERE mbrIntersects(ogc_geom,GeomFromText('POLYGON(-18 120,-10 120,-10 140,-18 140)'))
```

I've tried MBRContains, ST_Contains, MBRWithin and ST_Intersects. I've also tried switching the longitude and latitude. All of these things have done nothing.

I've also tried the following

```
SELECT mbrIntersects(ogc_geom,GeomFromText('POLYGON(-18 120,-10 120,-10 140,-18 140)')) FROM `polygons`
```

The above simply returned all the results and didn't really achieve anything.

So, in short, I would like to know how to retrieve all polygons from a MySQL database that are within a provided WKT polygon.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. your polygon isn't closed, the last point needs to be the same as
   the first point
2. you need one extra level of parenthesis as a POLYGON
   consists of an outer shape plus an optional set of inner shapes
   ('holes')

Working query:

```
SELECT * FROM `polygons` 
 WHERE mbrIntersects(ogc_geom,
   GeomFromText('POLYGON((-18 120,-10 120,-10 140,-18 140, -18 120))'));
```

note the double `((` after `POLYGON` and the extra fifth coordinate pair `-18 120` being the same as the first

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I already tried it closed and always had the extra parenthesis. It seems though that I never actually tried all of those things together, as its working fine now. Thanks

Comment: Also, just in case it helps someone else. The correct order is Longitude, Latitude for MySQL. You can also visualize your polygon here http://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html. Not directly related, but maybe will help others diagnose problems as there is very little documentation on MBR.

Comment: There is no fixed lat/lon order in MySQL ... order is an application choice

Answer (score 1):

use  select astext(ogc_geom) from `polygons`;
in my case return

POLYGON((48 68,76 68,76 106,48 106,48 68))

your code missing () in POLYGON() function. more detail check mysql document.